# Sencha Touch synch not saving to proxy

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a piece of code in a Sencha Touch v2 controller as shown below.  When this code is ran the count after the store.add is (6), the counter after the store.sync is (0) and the store.sync is succeeding.

NOTE: items holds 6 records received from a JsonP proxy, no errors are shown in the console and everything acts as though it was a full success.

```
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Sql'
    ],
    config: {
        models: ['Convention'],
        stores: ['Conventions']
    },

    // ***additional code*** //

    store.setProxy({
        type: 'sql',
        database: 'app',
        table: 'Conventions'
    });

    store.removeAll();
    store.sync({
        success: function(batch){
            store.add(items);
            console.log("Count before: " + store.getCount()); << Shows (6)
            store.sync({
                failure: function (batch, options) {
                    console.log('Convention Sql failure');
                },
                success: function(batch,options){
                    console.log("Count after: " + store.getCount()); << Shows (0)
                    console.log("Convention Sql success");
                    store.load();
                    Ext.Viewport.unmask();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The model is show here

```
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'logoId', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'seasonId', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'viewed', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'dateCreated', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'dateUpdated', type: 'string'}
    ]
}
```

and the store is here

```
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: [
    'Ext.data.proxy.Sql'
],
config: {
    model: 'app.model.Convention',
    autoLoad: false,
    sorters:[{
        property: 'name',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'sql',
        database: 'app',
        table: 'Conventions'
    }
}
```

Comment: Digging deeper, if I remove the ID from the items and let the model do an auto ID it works.  I can only assume that I need to define my ID.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research it seems that Sencha recently changed some of their code on how they handle IDs.  As such, if you are using code examples previous to this change you will get errors when you try to save to the ID field.

Sencha has added the clientIdProperty that you can add to the writer of a proxy and directly to the model.

Reference: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-clientIdProperty

> The name of a property that is used for submitting this Model's unique client-side identifier to the server when multiple phantom records are saved as part of the same Operation. In such a case, the server response should include the client id for each record so that the server response data can be used to update the client-side records if necessary. This property cannot have the same name as any of this Model's fields.

As such, my code above will have the following changes to the following where 'siteId' is my id being passed from the Json request and the ID on my server for the record.

model

```
    idProperty: 'id',
    clientIdProperty: 'siteId',
    identifier: 'uuid',
```

Controller

```
    store.setProxy({
        type: 'sql',
        database: 'app',
        table: 'Conventions',
        writer: {
            clientIdProperty: 'siteId'
        }
    });
```